# I've finally done it. I've created a web page that IE7 will crash when trying to open

Tags: internet-explorer-7, crash, html

http://www.ddrewdesign.com/portfolio/

I've run that on three different VMs and my brother's regular (and very adequate) beige box, and it crashes every one of them.

Anyone know what I might be doing wrong? I suspect it's a client-side issue, because the page loads fine in every other browser I've tested it in. I've already tried disabling all the js on the page.

Any ideas?

P.S. I know it looks like crap in IE, which is why I was in the middle of testing it.

Comment: well that's very useful to reject visitor if they are using IE!. congrats!

Comment: it would be even better if it crashed with a dialog box: "This wouldn't have happened if you used a better browser. Congratulations on being an ignorant mass."

Comment: Is your version of ie fully updated?

Comment: To add to nvl's answer you have more than 250 errors in your site.
check http://bit.ly/cvGs7z

Comment: Himanshu: Well, that might start to explain it. I recently have been converting my doctype from x1.0 strict to h4.1 loose. I guess this page fell through the cracks. Thanks for the head's up!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you have lots of [markup errors](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http://www.ddrewdesign.com/portfolio/&charset=(detect+automatically)&doctype=Inline&group=0&No200=1&verbose=1). IE crashes because its not tolerant like others.

For e.g. in many places, you have closed `<a>` twice. (see below, you closed before and after `<li>`)

```
<a href="/images/samples/print/bam1_3.png" rel="print[bam1]" class="lightwindow" caption="Broker Agent Magazine Cover Feature"  /><li>Broker Agent Magazine Cover Feature</li></a>
```

Comment: It's gonna take me a while to fix all these markup errors. 

BTW, I know it's bad to wrap an inline around a block element, but is that still true if you declare an inline element to be displayed as a block? Or do browsers not care?

Comment: you can make it happen with CSS.

Comment: Well, I've done some research, and here's what I found:

1) UL must have direct LI children only.

2) IMG is not considered a block-level element (thought it was, so was resigned to "whatever" when it came to validation).

3) Was able to clear about 180 of the errors with about 10 minutes of code, so I need to be more vigilant about my own website :|

Thanks so much, NVL. You get the Answer trophy.

Comment: thanks :). Always validate html, javascript and css. Will improve stability and cross-browser support. Keep posting if you find any problems.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, it's a lot more difficult to write a page that looks and works equally well in all modern browsers.